# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray runtime exception

Tags: java, android

This code gives runtime exception and I can't catch it. BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray doesn't return null or something like this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imbBytes, 0, imbBytes.length);
```

Note: when imbBytes is byte[] of .png gives error, when .JPG no.
I tried save png image in directory to check if byte[] was correct and everything worked fine.

Please help!!!

Comment: What runtime exception? Logcat? Any specifics?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> **Returns** The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decode.

Comment: Ys I know but it doesn't return null! I'm using google api 15

Comment: Sorry misread. Could you post the exact error and the line that produces it?

Comment: Nothing is printed on LogCat I only see error in Expressions windows during breakpoint: An exception occurred: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and then goes "Source not Found" on whie screen in eclipse

Comment: Well `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`... You probably don't have enough memory to decode. Maybe **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291029/android-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-outofmemoryerror-oom)** helps?