# Android memory leak?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

Hi I have an application that once it recieves a sms, it has to start collecting the location of the user every 1 minute. Everything starts ok i.e. if I send a text, then the sms processing wakes up and calls the location service to start collecting the location every 1 minute. But after some 30 minutes or so, my application crashes because of memory. I used heap in DDMS and observed the memory which keeps on increasing as time goes i.e. the size of the data object keeps getting higher. I also used the allocation tracker to see if there is any leak in my code and observed all the objects are that being created in my code are getting cleared. I am not sure where I am leaking. Please help me understand is this a memory leak? If yes, how can I find where the memory leak is? IF this is not a memory leak, how can I make the application run infinitely until I stop it.

Comment: When your application crashes, what is the exception and stack trace that you get? Where in your code do you think the problem is occurring?  Can you add some of your code to your question?

Comment: I am getting a java binder exception. It happens at random location as  soon as it crosses a min memory for an application.

Comment: What are the details of the exception?  Does the stack trace tell you which line in your class is causing the problem?  Please edit your question and add the full exception and stack trace you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at a post that I had recently.  I was new to finding memory leaks and the info in this post helped me to find all of my memory leaks and squash them:

[Android - Many OutOfMemoryError exceptions only on single Activity with MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136198/android-many-outofmemoryerror-exceptions-only-on-single-activity-with-mapview)